# Thrift TThreadPoolServer returns "Segmentation fault; core dumped;" when handle concurrent MySQL database requests

Tags: mysql, thrift, poco-libraries

I'm developing a simple assignment using Apache Thrift and the C++ `POCO` library. The assignment requires me to make a benchmark by creating multiple concurrent threads make the same request to the Thrift `TThreadPoolServer`.

This is my client-side code, where I creates 10 concurrent threads, all of them make the same `GET` request (request info from only one user `D`) to the server:

```
// define a MyWorker class which inherits Runnable
class MyWorker : public Runnable {
    public:

    MyWorker(int k = -1) : Runnable(), n(k) {
    }

    void run() {
        // create connection
        boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
        boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
        boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
        APIsClient client(protocol);
        try {
            transport->open();
            int res = -1;
            // make the request
            res = client.get("D"); 
            printf("Thread %d, res = %d \n", n, res);
            transport->close();
        } catch (TException te) {
            cout << te.what() << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    int n;
};

void handleBenchmarkTest(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) {
        //TODO!
        const int N = 10;
        MyWorker w[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) w[i] = MyWorker(i);
        Thread t[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) t[i].start(w[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) t[i].join(); // wait for all threads to end

        cout << endl << "Threads joined" << endl;
    }
```

I implemented my server using `TThreadPoolServer`. This is the the handler function when the server receive a `GET` request:

```
   // this function make use of POCO::Data   
int getRequest(const std::string& _username) {
            int res = -1;
            Statement select(*mySQLsession);
            std::string match("'" + _username + "'");
            select << "SELECT counter FROM view_count_info WHERE username = " + match + " LIMIT 1;", into(res);
            select.execute();
            return res;
        }
```

Above are all of my codes. When I run the client-side benchmark app, this is what returned:

```
MySQL // from the try-catch block above
MySQL // from the try-catch block above
Thread 2, res = -1 // expected result
MySQL // from the try-catch block above
Thrift: Fri Jun 26 15:54:05 2015 TSocket::read() recv() <Host: localhost Port: 9090>Connection reset by peer
No more data to read.
THRIFT_ECONNRESET
No more data to read.
No more data to read.
Thrift: Fri Jun 26 15:54:05 2015 TSocket::read() recv() <Host: localhost Port: 9090>Connection reset by peer
THRIFT_ECONNRESET
Thrift: Fri Jun 26 15:54:05 2015 TSocket::read() recv() <Host: localhost Port: 9090>Connection reset by peer
THRIFT_ECONNRESET

Threads joined
```

In the server, the result is:

```
2015-06-26 08:54:00 : > Server is running
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
-1
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
2015-06-26 08:54:05 : handle GET request
D
D

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 5s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

I don't know why this happened. **One more thing, when I try to change to not use MySQL request in the server side (instead I just return a random integer for each request), the app runs well without any errors or warning.** So I guess the problem here is with the MySQL database. It does work if I only make 1 request at a time, but something goes wrong when there are multiple, concurrent `GET` requests are made.

Comment: Don't do threading without locking. Few libraries are thread-safe or even thread-aware. Threading is not trivial. Your code likely just invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (e.g. due a _data race_)

Comment: Thanks ! But I wonder, is it necessary to use locking in a system where many user create the same GET requests (not PUT, POST or DELETE) ?

Comment: Yes. "Few libraries are thread-safe or even thread-aware."; the database might not be modified, but the program memory/state certainly is!

Comment: I dunno what `TException` is, but it's likely to be a base class. So you should catch it by reference or, better yet, `const` reference.

Comment: @sbi I changed it to catch (const TException& te) and now it yield something like `THRIFT_ECONNRESET`, `No more data to read.` and `Connection reset by peer` (no more `MySQL`). Still don't know how to fix this yet :(

Comment: @rainman_TS7: I know nothing about Poco, but if you didn't know that polymorphism only works through pointers and references you might be in need of [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/140719).

Comment: (1) "*when I try to change to not use MySQL request in the server side (instead I just return a random integer for each request), the app runs well without any errors or warning. So I guess the problem here is with the MySQL database*" - correct. (2) I also recommend double-checking your `getRequest()` routine for potential [`xkcd 327`](https://xkcd.com/327/) problems.

Comment: "*But I wonder, is it necessary to use locking in a system where $whatever*" - obviously. The scenario and everything around you told us points in exactly that direction: thread conflicts.

Comment: @JensG So the problem is within thread conflicts and MySQL.. But I havent been able to find in what way do the threads conflict :(. Can you tell me more after looking at my getRequest function ?

Comment: The `getRequest()` function is vulnerable exactly in the way the linked comic demonstrates. This comment is way too short to explain SQL injection in full detail. But [there are](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon) some good [sources](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html) out there [in the web](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), to name just a few.

Comment: Where does `mySQLsession` come from?

Comment: @JensG It's a global variable in the server-side code. More details here: https://github.com/thaisonle94/thrift-demo-cpp-server/blob/master/CppServer.cpp#L243-L265.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JensG, I found out that the problem here is because I used a global variable `mySQLsession` to handle all the MySQL database requests, which causes threads conflict. Thanks you all again !